# Custom distance (histogram intersection) function in Matlab knnclassify

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to implement a custom distance measure in Matlab "knnclassify" function?
In particular, I am interested in classifying an example according to the distance between two vectors to be equal to histogram intersection (vectors are considered to be histograms). For two N-dimensional vectors, w1 and w2, the distance is:

```
dist(w1, w2)=sum_i_to_N min(w1(i), w2(i))
```

Comment: there is a class `knnclassify`. Do you want to know how to use that class for your problem, do you want to create your own class/function with more or less the same effect, or what is it that you are asking for?

Comment: I want to use a different distance measure in knnclassify function. I hope the edited post is clearer.

Comment: @cerebrou: I have edited my answer. This should help

Answer (score 1):

By examining the source of `knnclassify`, this relies on using `knnsearch`.  The parameter of the distance to use is supplied to this function when you look at the `knnclassify` source.  By looking at `knnsearch`, you certainly can implement this function yourself.  `knnsearch` allows you to specify a custom function as long as it can take in only two vectors of the same size.   These vectors are from the data sets that you are applying `knnclassify` to.  As such, create a new function or you can do it anonymously using either:

```
function [d] = histogramIntersection(w1, w2)
    d = sum(min([w1,w2],[],2));
```

... or you can do this anonymously:

```
f = @(w1,w2) sum(min([w1,w2],[],2));
```

However, what you're going to have to do to incorporate this into `knnclassify` is that you will have to modify the source and include an additional condition in the `switch` statement so that you can include histogram intersection as a choice.  Once you do that, you can either provide `@f` as input into the `knnsearch` call, or make some room in the code and define a `histogramIntersection` method like above, then use `@histogramIntersection` as input into `knnclassify`.  This input should replace the string that is input into `knnclassify` that specifies the kind of distance measure you want.

---

`tl;dr`: You can do it but you'll have to modify the `knnclassify` source if you want to do this.  Alternatively, you can see what `knnclassify` is doing, then just pull out the relevant calls that pertain to just your case and place your custom histogram intersection method accordingly, create a new file and just run this file.  That way you don't need to mess with MATLAB's original source.